# Query unique author ids with published post of type job

Tags: query, author

I'm trying to come up with a simple query to return an array of unique author IDs that have a post_status of 'publish' and a post_type  of 'job'.

I know I can query using:

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'job',
'post_status' => 'publish'
);
$published_jobs = new WP_Query( $args );
```

But this seems horribly inefficient to iterate through the results when all I want is an array of unique author IDs. At most we will have 30 or so authors, but could have thousands of job posts.

Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most efficient means would be to query directly via [`wpdb`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb):

```
$author_ids = $wpdb->get_col(
    "
    SELECT DISTINCT post_author
    FROM $wpdb->posts
    WHERE post_type = 'job'
    AND post_status = 'publish'
    "
);
```